# How can I override laravel logout core event?

Tags: laravel, events, overriding

I'm trying to broadcast Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout. Is it possible to override or extend this core event so as to include BroadcastOn method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override the core logout event. There are two ways about this problem. Either way, you will have to fire your custom event.

1. Override `loggedOut()` method in `AuthenticatesUsers`:

You will have to create your custom event and override `loggedOut()` method in `AuthenticatesUsers` to fire it manually like so:

```
protected function loggedOut(Request $request)
{
    event(new CustomLogoutEvent());
}
```

This will fire the core event and your custom one.

2. Override `SessionGuard` to override `logout()` (lengthy and not suggested):

`logout()` in `SessionGuard` is where the core logout event is triggered. Override it to only fire your custom event. This way only one logout event is fired.

Here is how to override guards: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards